# Yii2 envelope single data in JSON response

Tags: php, json, rest, yii2, envelope

I went through offical guide and found a way to envelop JSON data like this.

```
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
    public $serializer = [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\Serializer',
        'collectionEnvelope' => 'items',
    ];
}
```

This works perfect when I have a collection and then I have a response like this.

```
{
     products:....
}
```

But what I want to do is that i have a envelope for single data. For example if I do products/10 GET request to get.

```
{
    product:
}
```

Hope somebody figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Single Data Envelope is not supported by [\yii\rest\Serializer](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-serializer.html). At least until Yii 2.0.6 only collections get enveloped in order to add `_links` and `_meta` data objects to the response.

To envelope single data resource objects you'll need to override **ActiveController**'s default **view action** within your Controller :

```php
public function actions() 
{
    $actions = parent::actions();
    unset($actions['view']);
    return $actions;
}

public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = Product::findOne($id);
    return ['product' => $model];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old, but I just bumped into here with the same problem.

And found a better (I think) solution: create your own serializer class extending \yii\rest\Serializer:

```
class Serializer extends \yii\rest\Serializer
{
  public $itemEnvelope;

  public function serializeModel($model)
  {
      $data = parent::serializeModel($model);
      if($this->itemEnvelope)return [$this->itemEnvelope=>$data];
      return $data;
  }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
    public $serializer = [
    'class'              => '[your-namespace]\Serializer',
    'collectionEnvelope' => 'list',
    'itemEnvelope'       => 'item'
];
```